# Equivalence class and how to find it

Tags: equivalence-relations

I need to find equivalence classes of relation $\sim$
\begin{array}{l}
x\sim y \Leftrightarrow 4 \mid\left(x^{3}-y^{3}\right) \\
\text { for } x, y \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{array}

I have shown that $\sim$ is equivalence  relation. I blind guessed that all even numbers will be one equivalence  class, so my question is is there some  systematic  approach to this problem?
Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Essentially, you want to use $x^3-z^3=x^3-y^2+y^3-z^3$. But you can also use the fact that $x\sim y$ if and only if either both numbers are odd or both numbers are even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $x\sim y \iff $ $x^{3}$ and $y^{3}$ leave the same remainder when divided by $4$.

Write $x=4q+r$ with $r\in\{0,1,2,3\}$. Then $x \sim r$ (check!) and so it suffices to consider the equivalence class of $r$. In particular, there are at most four equivalence classes. In fact, it turns out that there are three equivalence classes: $[0]$, $[1]$, $[3]$, because $[2]=[0]$.

In other words, all even numbers are in the same class, but the odd numbers fall into two classes.

Comment: Thank you so much !